# ToggleButton State OnClick

Tags: android, variables, onclick, onclicklistener, togglebutton

How do I change the state of toggleButton Only after I click OK on a dialog box , and if i clicked Cancel toggleButton is not changed , my problem is toggleButton is switched always,So Is there an example or a specific implementation that needs to be done before ?

```
 toggle1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
 //   toggle1.setChecked(getDefaults("Toggle1S",this));
 //  setDefaults("Toggle1S", toggle1.isChecked(), this);

toggle1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (toggle1.isChecked()) {
            on.start();
            Using();
            if(Use.equals("1"))
            {//Wifi Function
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Filter ON sent using Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new MyAsyncTask().execute("filter_st","ON");
            }
            else{
                String temp = "Are you want to turn Filter ON using GSM";
                callCheck(SMStitle,temp);
                sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, messages[0], null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Filter ON sent using GSM number"+number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                               

            }

    public void callCheck(String c,String d)
    {
        // Creating alert Dialog with one Button

        AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        fishtank.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog1.setTitle(c);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog1.setMessage(d);


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog1.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog1.show();
    }
```

Comment: Your posted code is missing closing brackets, specifically in your first onClick method. Does this compile?

Comment: No, I Removed everything and kept the part that the question about because I just need at least an example :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i understand your question seem to be fix easily consider this code
1-

```
alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       toggelBt.toggle();
                }
            });
```

2- and on other way u can save your State On runtime in boolean Variable in each calling ToggleButton Onclick method (using **sharedPreference** instead boolean for saving and using on next app startup)  then

```
 Boolean CheckState
 ...
 alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       if(checkState)//should set uncheck now
                             toggelBt.setChecked(false);
                       else
                             toggelBt.setChecked(true);
                }
            });
```

hop to be usefull :)

Comment: Thanks,that should be enough :D